# Multiple do_shortcode in page template

Tags: php, shortcode

Is it possible to nest multiple shortcodes with `do_shortcode`?

Using visual composer and easytable with the visual editor, the classic editor displays:

```
[vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][vc_accordion][vc_accordion_tab title="Section 1"][easytable]table stuff[/easytable][/vc_accordion_tab][vc_accordion_tab title="Section 2"][/vc_accordion_tab][/vc_accordion][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

I have attempted something like this:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][vc_accordion][vc_accordion_tab title="Section 1"][vc_column_text] [table]
' .$sometabledata. ' is some data
[/table][/vc_column_text][/vc_accordion_tab][vc_accordion_tab title="Section 2"][/vc_accordion_tab][/vc_accordion][/vc_column][/vc_row]' );
```

However, this seems to generate the accordion, but the table is then lost.  Separately the table works with:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[table]mydata[/table]' );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you need this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[your-first-shortcode]'.'[your-second-shortcode]'); ?>
```

Just write a dot between your shortcodes...

Try:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][vc_accordion][vc_accordion_tab title="Section 1"][vc_column_text]'.'[table]'.$sometabledata.'[/table]'.'[/vc_column_text][/vc_accordion_tab][vc_accordion_tab title="Section 2"][/vc_accordion_tab][/vc_accordion][/vc_column][/vc_row]' ); ?>
```

Comment: Great. I'm glad I helped.